# update-initramfs -u fails after installing new kernel

Tags: linux, command-line, kali-linux, linux-kernel, initrd

I compiled and installed a new kernel, 4.19.10 following this guide.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

I had done the same in the past without any issues but this time `update-initramfs -u` fails with the following error:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.10
find: ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_tiVSPO/lib/modules/4.19.10/kernel’: No such file or directory
```

I did both apt update and apt dist-upgrade without any issues but update-initramfs, fails. Update-grub also works, as below:

```
root@Kali:~/Downloads#  df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G   11M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdg2       437G   40G  375G  10% /
tmpfs            16G   52M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdg1       480M   16M  464M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G   16K  3.2G   1% /run/user/131
tmpfs           3.2G   44K  3.2G   1% /run/user/0

root@Kali:~/Downloads# df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            4105128    570  4104558    1% /dev
tmpfs           4106797   1058  4105739    1% /run
/dev/sdg2      29130752 692911 28437841    3% /
tmpfs           4106797     31  4106766    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4106797      3  4106794    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4106797     16  4106781    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdg1             0      0        0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs           4106797     24  4106773    1% /run/user/131
tmpfs           4106797     35  4106762    1% /run/user/0
```

dpkg -l | grep linux-image

```
root@Kali:~/Downloads# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-amd64           4.18.20-2kali2                        amd64        Linux 4.18 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.19.0-1-amd64               4.19.9-1                              amd64        Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ii  linux-image-4.19.9-custom                4.19.9-1                              amd64        Linux kernel, version 4.19.9-custom
ii  linux-image-amd64                        4.19+101                              amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

dpkg -l

```
ii  linux-base                               4.5                                   all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-compiler-gcc-7-x86                 4.18.20-2kali2                        amd64        Compiler for Linux on x86 (meta-package)
ii  linux-compiler-gcc-8-x86                 4.19.9-1                              amd64        Compiler for Linux on x86 (meta-package)
ii  linux-config-4.18:amd64                  4.18.20-2kali2                        amd64        Debian kernel configurations for Linux 4.18
ii  linux-config-4.19:amd64                  4.19.9-1                              amd64        Debian kernel configurations for Linux 4.19
ii  linux-headers-4.18.0-kali3-amd64         4.18.20-2kali2                        amd64        Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali3-amd64
ii  linux-headers-4.18.0-kali3-common        4.18.20-2kali2                        all          Common header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali3
ii  linux-headers-4.19.0-1-amd64             4.19.9-1                              amd64        Header files for Linux 4.19.0-1-amd64
ii  linux-headers-4.19.0-1-common            4.19.9-1                              all          Common header files for Linux 4.19.0-1
ii  linux-headers-4.19.9-custom              4.19.9-1                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for 4.19.9-custom on amd64
ii  linux-headers-amd64                      4.19+101                              amd64        Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
ii  linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-amd64           4.18.20-2kali2                        amd64        Linux 4.18 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.19.0-1-amd64               4.19.9-1                              amd64        Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ii  linux-image-4.19.9-custom                4.19.9-1                              amd64        Linux kernel, version 4.19.9-custom
ii  linux-image-amd64                        4.19+101                              amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
ii  linux-kbuild-4.18                        4.18.20-2kali2                        amd64        Kbuild infrastructure for Linux 4.18
ii  linux-kbuild-4.19                        4.19.9-1                              amd64        Kbuild infrastructure for Linux 4.19
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                     4.19.9-1                              amd64        Linux support headers for userspace development
ii  linux-source-4.18                        4.18.20-2kali2                        all          Linux kernel source for version 4.18 with Debian patches
ii  linux-source-4.19                        4.19.9-1                              all          Linux kernel source for version 4.19 with Debian patches
rc  live-tools                               1:20171207                            all          Live System Extra Components
ii  llvm                                     1:7.0-46                              amd64        Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM)
ii  llvm-6.0                                 1:6.0.1-9.2                           amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies
ii  llvm-6.0-dev                             1:6.0.1-9.2                           amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, libraries and heade
ii  llvm-6.0-runtime                         1:6.0.1-9.2                           amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, IR interpreter
ii  llvm-7                                   1:7.0.1-1                             amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technolo
```

uname -r

```
root@Kali:~/Downloads# uname -r
4.19.10
```

ls /boot

```
config-4.18.0-kali3-amd64  efi   initrd.img-4.18.0-kali3-amd64  System.map-4.18.0-kali3-amd64  vmlinuz-4.18.0-kali3-amd64
config-4.19.10             grub  initrd.img-4.19.10             System.map-4.19.10             vmlinuz-4.19.10
```

What could be causing `update-initramfs -u` to be failing now?